# Как отобразить сообщение посередине родительской формы?

Tags: c#

Всем привет. Вывожу сообщения так:

`MessageBox.Show("Please add jobs");`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно вывести MessageBox посередине родительской формы? Как вариант, можно выводить свою форму с сообщением, но хотелось бы узнать ответ именно на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: Стандартными методами никак. Разве что размещайте родительскую форму посередине экрана (т.к. окно отбражается посередине экрана)

Comment: Делайте кастомные MessageBox и выводите его где угодно

Comment: Про кастомные я написал сразу в вопросе. Понятно. Всем спасибо.

Comment: nick_n_a, форма будет выводиться там, где пользователь ее оставил.

Comment: Немного почитал форумы по этому вопросу. К сожалению, без своей формы этого сделать нельзя.

Comment: Кастомная форма + `WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"`

Answer (score 2):

Создать собственную форму, настроить его, как хочется, и использовать вместо стандартного MessageBox.

**Добавить конструктор с сообщением**

```
public partial class MessageForm : Form
    {
        public MessageForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        // Конструктор формы с сообщением
        public MessageForm(string message)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            // Записываем сообщение в уже установленый на форме label
            label1.Text = message;
        }
    }
```

**Добавьте метод показывающий ваше сообщение где вам надо**

```
/// <summary>
/// Показать сообщение в форме размещенной по центру
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">Сообщение</param>
private void ShowMessageForm(string message)
{         
    MessageForm form = new MessageForm(message);

    //Теперь положение формы определяется  form.Location
    form.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;

    //вычеляем ценрт формы с упреждение размеров нашей формы
    //по ширине (Исходная точка Х + Растояние до центра - Половину ширины нашей формы)
    //по высоте (Исходная точка Y + Растояние до центра - Половину высоты нашей формы)
    form.Location = new Point(Location.X + Width / 2 - form.Width / 2, Location.Y + Height / 2 - form.Height / 2);

    form.Show();
}
```

**Вызовете метод**

```
int kolichestvoPopytok = 21;
ShowMessageForm($"Я сделал это с {kolichestvoPopytok.ToString()} раза");
```

*Спасибо за внимание*